# Picker View - Exibir uma ImageView de acordo com a soma de valores

Tags: swift, xcode, if, else

Olá.

Estou tentando trabalhar com Picker View para exibir uma combinação de valores.

```
 var pickerDataSource = [["a", "b", "c", "d"],["1","2","3","4"]];
```

A dúvida é; como somo resultados dentro de uma condição?

```
        if(row == 0)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    }
    else
        if(row == 1)

    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    }
    else if(row == 1)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.greenColor();
    }
    else if(row == 3)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.blueColor();
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Voce colocou duas vezes `else if (row == 1)`. A segunda condição nunca vai ser executada.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro tens que saber qual é o array que quer extrair o valor. Se for o caso do array de números, utiliza o [1], que seria o segundo índice do seu array pickerDataSource. O [row] seria o índice que querer extrair do array de números, conforme o seu código assim utilizei o **row**.

Para extrair o valor utilize este código:

```
pickerDataSource[1][row]
```

Com isso você tem o valor para realizar os cálculos.

Comment: Okay, o que estou tentando fazer é;

Se o valor da pickerDataSource(num) é igual 1 e o valor dapickerDataSource(Letra) é igual a A.

Abro uma imagem de fundo, se é diferente, abro outra.

No caso do exemplo, estou mudando a cor somente.

Comment: tem como colocar imagens do seu código aqui, tenho que saber, para poder responder. Aguardo.

Comment: Estou na aula, não tenho o arquivo aqui.

Coloco mais tarde. valeuuu!

Comment: Cara, consegui resolver aqui. Depois posto a solução. Valeuuuuu a força.

Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

```
if pickerDataSource[0][row] == "a" && pickerDataSource[1][row] == "1"{

    print ("coloque a cor desejada")

}
else{

    print ("coloque outra cor")

}
```

*Antes do else, vc pode colocar um else if e ir colocando outra possibilidades de valores e cores para o resultado.*